# Integration of Apache Shiro into Quarkus framework

Tags: quarkus, shiro

Has anyone tried to integrate Apache Shiro within the Quarkus framework ? What were the joint points ?

Tried using the Jakarta EE integration but failed with it

Tried also using the Spring DI extension of quarkus to make work of the shiro spring integration